# How to create file on linux server using java

Tags: java, linux, file

Currently I am shifted my server to linux from windows and I am facing some problem in my java webservice. In that I am creating a file in windows D drive. now I want to create that on linux server too. but I dont know how to give path and how to create (since it don't have drives as windows). so need some help for this. I am posting my java code below.

```
private static void receiveImg(String pic_bitmap) {
    FileOutputStream fos;
    try {

        fos = new FileOutputStream("D:\\AllImages\\ProfilePic\\Test.png");
        byte byteArray[] = Base64.decodeBase64(pic_bitmap);
        fos.write(byteArray);
        fos.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Linux does not use Windows drive letters, where on the Linux system do you want to store your files. I repeat, can't be on "D" drive.

Comment: @Elliott Frisch thanks for suggestion. Can you tell how we can use url or path with port number in file path?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read file on Windows and Linux from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25307720/608639), [File path names for Windows and Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20979625/608639), etc.

Answer (score 1):

This should work. See below for more considerations

```
private static void receiveImg(String pic_bitmap) {
    FileOutputStream fos;
    try {

        fos = new FileOutputStream("/tmp/test.png");
        byte byteArray[] = Base64.decodeBase64(pic_bitmap);
        fos.write(byteArray);
        fos.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Note that you need to know the structure of the linux server to save it in a more suited place. If you can ssh onto the server you can run 'ls /' command to see the root folder structure. If you are not deploying the code yourself you may need a DevOps person to help you understand the folder structure on the destination server where you are deploying the code.

Comment: thanks for the help. Can we use url or path with port number in file path?

Comment: Not with this code. Note: your code is a bit out of date. https://dzone.com/articles/fileinputstream-fileoutputstream-considered-harmful. Use Files.newOutputStream instead. 

With regards to a remote server, you'll need something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40590372/how-to-write-a-string-to-a-file-located-in-remote-server-linux

Answer (score 0):

this could help you. It does not save an image, but that should not matter.

```
public void saveImage(String filename) { // filename ( path: linux ): /directory/filename 
    if(filename!=null){
        try {
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filename));
            oos.writeObject('objectToWrite');
            oos.flush();
            oos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }           
    }else{
        System.out.println("NullPointerException");
    }
}
```